# The defined BANDWIDTH in M3U8 and Linux tc

Tags: m3u8, trafficshaping

I have the following m3u8 file

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:7
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=87835,RESOLUTION=426x240,CODECS="avc1.640015"
240-34/media_0.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=177512,RESOLUTION=426x240,CODECS="avc1.640015"
240-28/media_0.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=267977,RESOLUTION=854x480,CODECS="avc1.640015"
480-34/media_0.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=499454,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.640015"
720-34/media_0.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=957645,RESOLUTION=1920x1080,CODECS="avc1.640015"
1080-34/media_0.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1903257,RESOLUTION=1920x1080,CODECS="avc1.640015"
1080-28/media_0.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=3907896,RESOLUTION=1920x1080,CODECS="avc1.640015"
1080-22/media_0.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=8265879,RESOLUTION=1920x1080,CODECS="avc1.640015"
1080-16/media_0.m3u8
```

I want to run a Linux tc command to shape the bandwidth for each defined bandwidth in the previous file, but I am not sure the bandwidth value is bps or kbps.

for example, I want to run a tc command for the follows

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=87835,RESOLUTION=426x240,CODECS="avc1.640015"
240-34/media_0.m3u8
```

which command is right

```
tc qdisc add dev eth1 root tbf rate 87835kbit burst 16kbit latency 2ms
```

or

```
tc qdisc add dev eth1 root tbf rate 87835 burst 16kbit latency 2ms
```

Comment: Its defined in the RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8216

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section [4.3.4.2.  EXT-X-STREAM-INF of the HLS RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8216#section-4.3.4.2) says

```
      BANDWIDTH

      The value is a decimal-integer of bits per second.  It represents
      the peak segment bit rate of the Variant Stream.
```

So it's bps and you would just pass `87835` as a `rate` param for your `tc` command.

Depending on what you want to do, just be aware that it is defined as the **peak** bit rate and not the **average** bit rate.